# What is the difference between spin glass and spin liquid?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, spin-models

What is the difference between [spin glass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_glass) and [spin liquid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_spin_liquid)?

Do they both originate from frustration?

Comment: They are both frustrated. The difference resides in the level of quantum fluctuation. The spin glass has no quantum fluctuation, but the spin liquid has very strong quantum fluctuation.

Comment: Because they are classical spin models, or the spin is large such that the fluctuation is weak.

Answer (score 7):

In **spin liquids**, the ordered state is  broken by zero-point fluctuations even at $T=0$. Even though it is common for spin liquids to be frustrated, it is not necessarily so. The $S=1$ Heisenberg spin chain (AFM), for example, is a spin liquid without being frustrated.
 The name spin liquid comes (I believe), from the exponentially decaying correlation (like in liquids).
**Spin glass**  on the other hand is always frustrated. The easiest way of thinking about spin glass is by picturing an Ising model with random couplings $J_{ij}$. The actual ground state of such a system will be hard to determine, as there will be many metastable states. Again - just like in regular glass.

Comment: What about spin ice?